How should we organize our pipelines?
In a large cloud software project, we are using Azure DevOps yaml pipelines (in one DevOps project) for various purposes:

validation of changes (set up as prerequisites for pull requests)
build of individual components and the entire application
composition of setup packages
deployment of internal web-based tools and of test instances of the cloud software itself

Moreover, various versions/variants of the cloud software are maintained/released in parallel, each of whose codebases is kept in a separate branch on the source repositories. Of course, plenty of the above pipelines are also run every now and then based on various feature branches.
As a result, especially the less technical people in the team are interested

only in a small subset of the above pipelines (think 10 out of 100)
only when run based on a specific subset of branches (again, think 5 out of 50)
usually only in the latest run of each of them, separately for each branch

Now, looking at how pipelines are represented in Azure DevOps, there appears to be virtually no support for these requirements:

Using the built-in pipelines interface, it is simply too hard for these non-technical people to find the relevant runs of specific pipelines (let alone see exactly all of the relevant runs in some kind of a combined summary).
Despite there being lots of extensions for DevOps on the marketplace, I could not find anything that seemed to really cover these requirements.
My related question for something that supports these requirements on Software Recommendations SE has not yielded any results.

As I do not think our requirements are actually in any way unusual, this leads me to conclude that maybe our approach of using Azure DevOps for it is off.
Is there a recommended standard approach for the described scenario with respect to organizing the pipelines and conveying/finding current pipeline run results?
